# Scapy - how to check packet type of sniffed packets

Tags: python, scapy, sniffing

I am sniffing packets and need to know which packets are ICMPv6 Echo Request packets and which are UDP packets.

I know that I can do

```
P = sniff(filter='ip6 and host fe80::xx:xx:xx:xx',count=0)

IP in P  #will return false (my packets are IPv6)
UDP in P #will return true (when the specific packet is indeed UDP)
```

but I don't know how to check for ICMPv6 packets, and even more specifically ICMPv6 Echo *Request* packets... It doesn't seem like I can even check for anything IP version 6:

IPv6, IP6, ipv6, ip6, icmpv6, ICMPv6, icmp6, ICMP6 all return a

```
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Does anyone know of a way to do such a thing?

Comment: What version of scapy do you have? Running scapy 2.1.0 (on Python 2.7.2 on OS X 10.8.5), `IPv6 in P` works fine for me.

Comment: In particular, after making sure I captured exactly one UDP v6 packet: `UDP in P` is False, `UDP in P[0]` is True, `IPv6 in P` is False, `IPv6 in P` is True, `P[0][IPv6]` is an IPv6 packet, …

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Scapy v1.x, it does not handle IPv6, as it says in various places in the documentation. For example, in [Download and Installation](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/installation.html):

> **Scapy v2.x.** The current development version adds several features (e.g. IPv6).

If you're using 2.x, it should work just fine with `IPv6`. For example, on my computer (Scapy 2.1.0, Apple pre-installed Python 2.7.2, OS X 10.8.5):

```
>>> P = sniff(filter='ip6', count=0)
… make sure to capture an IPv6 UDP packet …
>>> UDP in P
False
>>> IPv6 in P
False
>>> UDP in P[0]
True
>>> IPv6 in P[0]
True
>>> P[0][IPv6]
<IPv6  version=6L tc=0L fl=0L plen=98 nh=UDP …
>>> ICMPv6EchoRequest in P[0]
False
>>> ICMPv6EchoRequest
<class 'scapy.layers.inet6.ICMPv6EchoRequest'>
```

Comment: Ahhhh, there we go, I feel stupid. It was my version!! Thank you!